# I can't pick an element from my array with my variable

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need you help.I'm trying to extract some values from my array, but I can't.

Here is my controller:

```
$initiated =  \App\Invitation::where('inviter_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->get();
```

Here is my view :

```
{{$initiated['id']}} // undefined index error
```

And if I try with `{{$initiated->id}}` I have Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

And here is my array:

```
[{"id":578,"inviter_id":"545","target_id":"542","timestamp":"0","accepted":"1","read":"0"},{"id":606,"inviter_id":"504","target_id":"542","timestamp":"0","accepted":"1","read":"0"},{"id":608,"inviter_id":"548","target_id":"542","timestamp":"0","accepted":"1","read":"0"},{"id":613,"inviter_id":"553","target_id":"542","timestamp":"0","accepted":"1","read":"0"}]
```

So, I need to pick all id's from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this query you're retrieving a collection, and a collection is an iterable object so, in your view you have to iterate it in order to get the `id` of each model inside your collection.

```php
<!-- In your view -->

@foreach($initiated as $record)
{{ $record->id }} 
@endforeach
```

If You need to Get only the id use the [`pluck` method](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck)

```php
$initiated = \App\Invitation::where('inviter_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->pluck('id);
```

I've used the object notation, since the collection is filled with `Invitation` objects. But the array notation (`$record['id']`) will work as well since each Model can be casted to array.

Comment: Thank you bro, this is the correct answer to my question :) Good explain, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` method returns a collection instead of a single record. Use `first()` method instead of `get()` to get your desired results.

Comment: Yes but now, with `first()`, I'm getting only first record, and I need all records from id, because at `dd($initiated)` I'm getting an array with 3 records, and I want to extract from that only `id`.

Comment: @Andrew if you need all records, then you must loop through them to get your desired results. This is much more of a logic problem than a Laravel problem. It's on you, not on Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try Add both `get()` annd `first()`

```
 $initiated =  \App\Invitation::where('inviter_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->get()->first();
```

Worked for me last time:)